# Bash script to copy backup file bigger than and it's subfiles sorted by date

Tags: bash, file-transfer, freebsd

I have Veeam backing up to a nas, but I'd like to copy the last backups to a removable unit every day.
This means copying the vbk and vib files related to the vbk.

Example of file listing I have:

```
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel  255999550464 May 27 23:24 SRV-DATA2017-05-27T220411.vbk
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel     304592896 May 28 22:04 SRV-DATA2017-05-28T220053.vib
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel    1070917632 May 29 22:04 SRV-DATA2017-05-29T220034.vib
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel    1196136448 May 30 22:04 SRV-DATA2017-05-30T220037.vib
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel    1326031872 May 31 22:04 SRV-DATA2017-05-31T220040.vib
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel     865165824 Jun  1 22:04 SRV-DATA2017-06-01T220044.vib
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel    1169223168 Jun  2 22:04 SRV-DATA2017-06-02T220046.vib
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel  257745453568 Jun  3 23:25 SRV-DATA2017-06-03T220436.vbk
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel     280499200 Jun  4 22:04 SRV-DATA2017-06-04T220044.vib
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel     889518592 Jun  5 22:04 SRV-DATA2017-06-05T220046.vib
-rwxr--r--  1 root  wheel     955318784 Jun  6 22:04 SRV-DATA2017-06-06T220055.vib
```

Using `find . -type f -size +10G -mtime -10` I can get files bigger that 10Gigs modified in the last 10 days.
I know I can have the latest vbk this way.

How can I get the vib files following this vbk ?

I was thinking about extracting the date of the vbk file and get all the vib files modified after that date, but I don't know ho to translate this into bash.
I tried `find . -type f -size +10G -mtime -10 | xargs stat  | cut -d '"' -f2` to get the date but what do I do with the date after that ?

I'm trying to do that on a nas4free unit, meaning FreeBSD.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’ve identified the vbk file (say, `$vbk`), do

```
find . -type f -newer "$vbk"
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this -newer switch. Definitively easier this way.